# Bird's Probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

Please, could somebody help me to figure this exercise?

You collect data on the wing lengths $(Y_i)$ of $50$ bald eagles in one sample.  The average wing length ($Y$ sample average) is $89$ cm and the variance ($s^2$) is $16$ cm.

- What is $P(Y \leq 85)$?
- What is $P(Y \geq 97)$?
- What is $P(82 \leq Y \leq 98)$?

If you could sample $n=50$ birds $10$ times (that is, $N=10$), what do you expect the sample average to be?
What is the standard error of the mean?

Comment: (-1) It is not such a good idea to post a bunch of questions without giving any ideas you have about them, or what methods you think you need to use or what you need help with . It makes potential answerers think that you are lazy and just want others to do your work for you.

Comment: The unit of the variance in this case is cm$^2$. The unit of standard deviation is cm.

Comment: It's a fair your comment Fortuon Paendra. However, it is not the case!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will have to understand is that since you are collecting data on 50 birds, the distribution of this **sample** is normal, regardless of the distribution of the wing lengths of the birds.

Now, if you know that, then the **sample mean**, denoted typically by $\mu_\bar{x}$ is

$$\mu_\bar{x} = \frac{\overbrace{89 + 89 + 89 + ... + 89}^{\text{50 times}}}{50} = 89
$$

And the **sample variance**, denoted by $\sigma_{\bar{x}}^2$ is

$$\sigma^2_\bar{x} = \frac{16}{50} = 0.32
$$

I'll leave it to you to complete the question.